# pcie_ports=compat, why port can be treat as bridges

Tags: drivers, pci

http://redsymbol.net/linux-kernel-boot-parameters/3.2/

```
 compat  Treat PCIe ports as PCI-to-PCI bridges, disable the PCIe
                    ports driver.
```

In my understanding, PCIe port( here mean root ports? ) is a root port, why it can be treat as PCI-to-PCI bridges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the value is `pcie_ports=compat` it means the Linux pci ( pcie ) driver will not manage some PCIe capabilities
of all ( Root, Upstream, and Downstream ) Type 1 ports.
In particular, these Linux pci port services are not started --
**AER**, **PME**, **DPC**, **Hotplug**, and **Bandwidth Notification**

In that case, those capabilities may be managed by the system ( BIOS etc. ), or not; but Linux will not involve itself in them.
To Linux, then, these Type 1 ports are just that; i.e. they are simply P2P bridges.